# Is it possible to configure SCID to use English descriptive notation?

Tags: notation, scid

I'm going through a classic book (Reti's Modern Ideas in Chess), which uses English descriptive notation rather than algebraic notation.  I see there is an online resource which has converted the book to algebraic notation, but is it possible to configure SCID to use English descriptive notation instead of the default?  Links below.

http://www.openchessbooks.org/reti-mic/chapter1/combination.html
https://sourceforge.net/projects/scid/

An example of the book notation is

```
4. P - Q Kt 4
```

Which converts to the algebraic notation of

```
b4
```

Comment: A look through the help, the menus, and the option file doesn't seem to indicate that there's such an option. Of course, it's open source, so you could always add the option yourself...

Comment: That's what I thought.  If you want to post the comment as an answer I will mark it as such, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the help, the menus, and the option file. I didn't see anything that looked like it could do this.

Of course, SCID is open source. If you know programming, you could always add this functionality yourself.